# How can I use Generics to make this FSM more flexible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I am trying to make an FSM that can be a bit more flexible by having a StateController base class that other controllers (PlayerController, AiController, etc) can derive from. So far the arguments passed have heavy dependencies with do not allow for such flexibility, hence, generics. Only thing is I cannot wrap my mind around the approach.

Here is the code for the FSM as is without the flexibility I was hoping to achieve.

StateController.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public class StateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public State currentState;
    public State previousState;
    public State remainInState;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!currentState)
            return;

        currentState.OnEnter(this);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!currentState)
            return;

        currentState.OnFixedUpdate(this);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!currentState)
            return;

        currentState.OnUpdate(this);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!currentState)
            return;

        currentState.OnLateUpdate(this);
    }

    public void ChangeState(State nextState)
    {
        if (nextState != remainInState)
        {
            currentState.OnExit(this);
            previousState = currentState;
            currentState = nextState;
            currentState.OnEnter(this);
        }
    }
}
```

State.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = ("State Controller/State"))]
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    public StateAction[] onEnter;
    public StateAction[] onFixed;
    public StateAction[] onUpdate;
    public StateAction[] onLate;
    public StateAction[] onExit;

    public StateTransition[] transitions;

    public void OnEnter(StateController controller)
    {
        ExecuteActions(controller, onEnter);
    }

    public void OnFixedUpdate(StateController controller)
    {
        ExecuteActions(controller, onFixed);
    }

    public void OnUpdate(StateController controller)
    {
        ExecuteActions(controller, onUpdate);
        CheckTransitions(controller);
    }

    public void OnLateUpdate(StateController controller)
    {
        ExecuteActions(controller, onLate);
    }

    public void OnExit(StateController controller)
    {
        ExecuteActions(controller, onExit);
    }

    private void ExecuteActions(StateController controller, StateAction[] actions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
        {
            actions[i].Execute(controller);
        }
    }

    private void CheckTransitions(StateController controller)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transitions.Length; i++)
        {
            bool result = transitions[i].condition.CheckCondition(controller);

            if (result == true)
            {
                controller.ChangeState(transitions[i].trueState);
            }
            else
                controller.ChangeState(transitions[i].falseState);
        }
    }
}
```

StateAction.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class StateAction : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void Execute(StateController controller);
}
```

StateCondition.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class StateCondition : ScriptableObject
{
   public abstract bool CheckCondition(StateController controller);
}
```

StateTransition.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class StateTransition
{
    public StateCondition condition;
    public State trueState;
    public State falseState;
}
```

But I want the flexibilty to use StateController.cs as a base class and be able to derive another class from it (obviously making it abstract and using protected virutal void for functions) like a PlayerController script...

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : StateController
{
    //Other Variables Specific to this class

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
    }

    //Other Functions Specific to this class
}
```

I figured the use of Generics could help with this since I have another script which can only take a StateController as an argument...

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = ("State Controller/Action Test"))]
public class ActionTest : StateAction
{
    public override void Execute(StateController controller /*place PlayerController Here instead */)
    {
        Debug.Log(controller.currentState);
    }
}
```

Generics could help but it's implementation is daunting to me. Here is an example of the above script with generics used to allow PlayerController to be passed in but would not remedy the system as State.cs would need T as an argument.

```
public abstract class StateAction<T> : ScriptableObject where T : StateController
{
    public abstract void Execute(T controller);
}

using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = ("State Controller/Action Test"))]
public class ActionTest : StateAction<PlayerController>
{
    public override void Execute(PlayerController controller)
    {
        Debug.Log(controller.currentState);
    }
}
```

I know the FSM needs to be restructured but is there anyone else who managed to rework a similar FSM with this approach?

Comment: Yes, post more code. I am curious why you need generic argument. By the looks of the current question, removing `<T>` and changing `T controller` to `StateController controller` will address the problem.

Comment: Or maybe have an interface type for `StateAction<IFoo<T>>`, but yeah, a bit more details on how you want to use it would be enlightening

Comment: I just edited the post to shed more light... sorry all i know it is alot of code, however, i hope it is more concise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated based on the comments*

Try:

```
public abstract class StateAction : ScriptableObject
{ 
    public abstract void Execute(StateController controller);
}

public abstract class StateAction<T> : StateAction
    where T : StateController
{
    public abstract void Execute(T controller);

    public sealed override Execute(StateController controller)
    {
        if (controller is T)
        {
            Execute((T)controller);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have variables like:

```
StateAction[] onEnter;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work becuase the variable needs to be able to hold a scriptableobject in it and i don't believe Interfaces can contain data objects :( The actual array StateAction[] onEnter is an array that will hold scriptable objects of type StateActions.

Comment: Then what about base abstract class: `class StateAction<T> : StateAction`, then `class StateAction : ScriptableObject`? @Dsolace See updated.

Comment: I changed around some of the permission levels and for some strange reason it works and I have no clue why... It seems your implementation was like a getter/setter version that would override the base and prevent other classes from changing it. But it kept saying the the sealed protection level wasn't appropriate and I needed a return type. I posted the change I made to your code just below your original answer and it seems to work!

Comment: I can't see your updated version for some reason. But yeah, feel free to remove `sealed` if it doesn't work for you.